# Sticky header in android project

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a view in my android project like : [image]

I want to show a header when I scroll down when the Title (lblHeaderJobTitle in the code below) reaches the top, and hide it back when the title is visible in the screen when I scroll up.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin4"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin4"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblHeaderJobTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/t4"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:MvxBind="Text Title"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblHeaderJobCompanyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin2"
            android:fontFamily="@font/mulish_bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/t2"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblHeaderJobTitle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/verticalSeparatorHeader"
            app:MvxBind="Text CompanyName"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/verticalSeparatorHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="|"
            android:fontFamily="@font/mulish_regular"
            android:textSize="@dimen/t2"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/lblHeaderJobCompanyName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/lblHeaderJobCompanyName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/lblHeaderJobLocation"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblHeaderJobLocation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/mulish_regular"
            android:textSize="@dimen/t2"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/lblHeaderJobCompanyName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/verticalSeparatorHeader"
            app:MvxBind="Text LblLocation"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/imgHeaderSeparator"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/silver"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblHeaderJobLocation"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollViewJobDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin4"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin4">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgBrandingLogo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_roundrect_ripple_light_border"
                    app:MvxBind="DrawableName DefaultCompanyPhotoDrawable"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblJobTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin2"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/t8"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/relativeLayoutJobDetail"
                app:MvxBind="Text Title"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgJobLocation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblJobTitle"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblJobCompanyName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin2"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin2"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mulish_bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/t4"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imgJobLocation"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imgJobLocation"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/verticalSeparator"
                app:MvxBind="Text CompanyName"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/verticalSeparator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="|"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mulish_regular"
                android:textSize="@dimen/t4"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/lblJobCompanyName"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/lblJobCompanyName"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/lblJobLocation"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblJobLocation"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mulish_regular"
                android:textSize="@dimen/t4"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/lblJobCompanyName"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/verticalSeparator"
                app:MvxBind="Text LblLocation"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutBtnGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin4"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin4"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

        <Button
            style="@style/Button.Tertiary"
            android:id="@+id/btnSaveNow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="24dp"
            android:paddingEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin2"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/frameLayoutApplyFix"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/frameLayoutApplyFix"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/frameLayoutApplyFix"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:MvxBind="Text BtnSave; Click SaveCommand"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my activity I tried this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create your application here
        _constraintLayoutHeader = FindViewById<ConstraintLayout>(Resource.Id.constraintLayoutHeader);
        _constraintLayoutBtnGroup = FindViewById<ConstraintLayout>(Resource.Id.constraintLayoutBtnGroup);

        ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)_constraintLayoutBtnGroup.LayoutParameters).Behavior = new StickyBottomBehavior(Resource.Id.frameLayoutApply, Resource.Id.nestedScrollViewJobDetail, EPosition.Bottom);
        ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)_constraintLayoutHeader.LayoutParameters).Behavior = new StickyBottomBehavior(Resource.Id.lblJobLocation, Resource.Id.nestedScrollViewJobDetail, EPosition.Top);

    }
```

In my custom behavior:

```
public class StickyBottomBehavior : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior
    {
        #region Properties

        private int _anchorId;

        private int _scrollViewId;

        private EPosition _position;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public StickyBottomBehavior(int anchorId, int scrollViewId, EPosition ePosition)
        {
            _anchorId = anchorId;
            _scrollViewId = scrollViewId;
            _position = ePosition;
        }

        #endregion

        public override bool OnStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, Java.Lang.Object child, View directTargetChild, View target, int axes, int type)
        {
            return (axes == ((int)Vertical));
        }

        public override void OnNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, Java.Lang.Object child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int type)
        {
            var anchor = coordinatorLayout.FindViewById(_anchorId);

            NestedScrollView scrollView = coordinatorLayout.FindViewById<NestedScrollView>(_scrollViewId);

            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)scrollView.LayoutParameters;

            int[] anchorLocation = new int[2];

            View childView = child.JavaCast<View>();

            anchor.GetLocationInWindow(anchorLocation);

            switch (_position)
            {
                case EPosition.Top:
                    if (anchorLocation[1] < 0)
                    {
                        childView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

                        layoutParams.TopMargin = childView.Height;
                        scrollView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        childView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

                        layoutParams.TopMargin = 0;
                        scrollView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                    }
                    break;

                case EPosition.Bottom:
                    if (anchorLocation[1] < 0)
                    {
                        childView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

                        layoutParams.BottomMargin = childView.Height + 8;
                        scrollView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        childView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

                        layoutParams.BottomMargin = 0;
                        scrollView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    public enum EPosition
    {
        Top,
        Bottom
    }
```

For the sticky buttons in the bottom it works very well but for the header there is smt wrong when I reach the Title in the top the screen is moving weirdly.

Demo: https://www.veed.io/view/6e1c9b71-b10d-46c7-a284-18b974a0bb7e

Is there another way to do that ? or there is smt wrong in my code ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Usually, the sticky header is included in the scrollview like your sticky buttons in the bottom. So you can create a TextView in the scrollview and change the value of isvisible when it scrolls.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: What I mean is that most of the solutions about the sticky header in the scrollview is putting the sticky header in the scrollview, just like you put the sticky button in it. If you put it out of the scrollview, there will be some conflicts when user scrolls the screen.